# Why do I get "FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2723" when adding text to a String.format?

Tags: android

I have this Runnable timer thread:

```
private Runnable updateTimerThreadRecording = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

            int secs = (int) (timeInMilliseconds / 1000);
            int mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;
            int hours = mins / 60;
            mins = mins % 60;
            String timer = "Recording Time: " + String.format("%02d", hours) + ":" + String.format("%02d", mins) + ":" + String.format("%02d", secs);
            timerValueRecord.setText(timer);
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }

    };
```

What I added is: "Recording Time: "
The original line of the String timer was:

```
String timer = "" + String.format("%02d", hours) + ":" + String.format("%02d", mins) + ":" + String.format("%02d", secs);
```

But since I added the Recording Time: 
I'm getting this exception. I tried to add this text in the String.format before the "%02d" but same exception.

Without it as the original line was there was no exception.
Without the text I added it was running fine and what I saw was: 00:00:00 and it was counting the seconds. But I want now to add a text so it will look like on the timerValueRecord TextView like this: Recording Time: 00:00:00

This is the Logcat:

```
11-16 19:18:46.505  20569-20753/com.test.webservertest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2723
    Process: com.test.webservertest, PID: 20569
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6334)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:890)
            at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17407)
            at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17407)
            at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17407)
            at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17407)
            at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17407)
            at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17407)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:360)
            at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17407)
            at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:7054)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4186)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4044)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3999)
            at com.test.webservertest.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:230)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at com.test.webservertest.MainActivity$3.run(MainActivity.java:272)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: You must not use threads to update the ui. So `Timer`/`TimerTask`, raw `Thread` and anything that creates threads are taboo. Luckily, repeated tasks don't need threads: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Repeating-Periodic-Tasks#handler or use a [`CountDownTimer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) with `millisInFuture` set to `Long.MAX_VALUE` so that it never runs out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to modify view fields inside another Thread (your Runnable) Android does not accept that, you need to make this change delegating to the thread you used on UI. The problem is not in the `String.format` is in `timerValueRecord.setText(timer);` You can try use the [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to post your runnable there. By now I don't know about perfomance issues on doing that, but beware about it.